# How to manage USB webcam image settings on guvcview? The "image control" options work fine with the built-in camera, but not with the USB one

Tags: usb, brightness, webcam, camera

I use Ubuntu 18.04; I have a built-in camera in my computer (low resolution) and a USB webcam. The USB camera works fine; however, when I open guvcview, I can change the image settings (brightness, contrast, saturation etc) of the built-in camera in the 'image controls' section, and when I open the built-in camera in other application such as zoom or google meets the image settings are applied. However, when I switch to the USB camera in guvcview, changing the image settings in the 'image controls' section has no effect in guvcview, although it changes the image settings in other applications. The problem is this is very inconvenient, because since I can't see the image change as I change the settings, I can't find the exact setting I want.
Is there a way to fix this?